# Django unexpected keyword argument "related_name"

Tags: django, django-models, typeerror

I have a series of tables defined in my Django models file and it told me to add the keyword `related_name` to a small group of my fields, since multiple fields pointed to the same table.  I did this, and now when i try to sync my database, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'related_name'
```

None of my related names are the same, so I'm not sure what I am missing...

Comment: Please add your model code.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out the error was coming from having a `related_name` argument defined in a non-foreignkey column.  Removing this fixed the error.